# How to avoide ZeroPadding in convolutional neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a convolutional neural network, that does better job than others for my dataset. The problem is with the `ZeroPadding2D` I need to place to account for down/up sampling; it creates artifacts in the output (zero samples). So, How can I avoid `ZeroPadding2D` option without changing the network structure (Layers). I need to maintain the structure as it's (no.layers) and may change the 
1- Filter
2- kernel
3- first dimension in my data (e.g 96)
4- any other options 
Bellow is my CNN

```
input_img = Input(shape=(96, 44, 1), name='full')  

x = GaussianNoise(.1)(input_img)
x = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = AveragePooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = AveragePooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = AveragePooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional
x = Conv2D(512, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.12)(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.12)(x)
x = ZeroPadding2D(((4, 0), (0, 0)))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='tanh', padding='same',
                 name='out')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you replace your `Upsampling`+ `ZeroPadding` sections with `Conv2DTranspose` , that might help to solve your issue.

Have a look here :

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose